# Moen 1225 replacement w/ new shower handle

Tags: shower, faucet, valve, cartridge, knobs

Replaced a 1225 Moen Cartridge along with a new pull out/push in handle. After trying 3 different handles I am still having no success with finishing up this job. The problem is after installing the knob and make sure the screw is tight (just tight enough to not crack the acrylic), pull the knob out, we have full flow of water, turn it to the left (hot water), turn to the right (cold water) like we should. However, when the knob is pushed back in to shut the flow of water off three things happen. First, the water does not turn off completely. Second, the center screw that holds the knob to the valve cartridge has to be physically pushed back in to shut the water off completely. And third, just for a further test a little pressure was constantly applied to the center screw to keep the water off, and while the knob was being turned to the left and right the water would start to run again. Not a full flow, more of a constant and aggressive drip. I have tried the screws (all too short) that came with the handles. At this point I am at a lost, I did try a longer screw, however, it may have been too long or not long enough. When I used that screw I was able to tighten the handle with no issues per se, however, when it was tighten down it resulted in the knob's inability to be pulled back out to turn the water back on.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Pictures of the handle and valve would help here. It sounds like the handle you have is not compatible with the cartridge or the shield around the cartridge.